# Extract Multiple nodes using XPath

Tags: java, xpath

I would like to use XPath to extract the "ImageUID" element value (i.e.{7f2535d0-9a41-4997-9694-0a4de569e6d9}) and the "URL128" element value (i.e. http://cachens.corbis.com/CorbisImage/thumb/15/53/42/15534232/42-15534232.jpg) from an xml string like below.  There can be multiple "Image" elements even though there is just one here.  The below code extracts only the URL128 value but I need to get the cooresponding ImageUID as well, any ideas?

```
String unescaped="<imagesXML><Images><Image><ImageUID Scope='Public' Type='Guid' Value='{7f2535d0-9a41-4997-9694-0a4de569e6d9}'/><CorbisID Scope='Public' Type='String' Value='42-15534232'/><Title Scope='Public' Type='String' Value='Animal'/><CreditLine Scope='Public' Type='String' Value='¬© Robert Llewellyn/Corbis'/><IsRoyaltyFree Scope='Public' Type='Boolean' Value='False'/><AspectRatio Scope='Public' Type='String' Value='1.500000'/><URL128 Scope='Public' Type='String' Value='http://cachens.corbis.com/CorbisImage/thumb/15/53/42/15534232/42-15534232.jpg'/></Image></Images></imagesXML>";

InputSource source = new InputSource(new StringReader(unescaped));
        XPath xPath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
        NodeList list = null;
        try
        {
            SimpleNamespaceContext nsCtx = new SimpleNamespaceContext();
            nsCtx.bindNamespaceUri("ns", "http://c1.net.corbis.com/");
            xPath.setNamespaceContext(nsCtx);
            list = (NodeList) xPath.evaluate("//ns:URL128/@Value", source, XPathConstants.NODESET);
        } catch (Exception ex)
        {
            log.error(ex.getMessage());
        }
        List<String> imageURLs = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (int i = 0; i < list.getLength(); i++)
        {
            imageURLs.add(list.item(i).getTextContent());
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this XPath 1.0 out:

```
 "/imagesXML/Images/Image/*[self::ImageUID or self::URRL128]/@Value"
```

As shown in your input, you don't actually need namespaces I think. Otherwise you can simply add them or select by `local-name()`.

Comment: thanks for the reply empo.  I didn't include all of my xml to make it easier to read. There is a part with a namespace.